# comparing innerHTML value with a string variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

```
function Open() {

  var cc = document.getElementById('FName');

  if ('Newfile.rtf' == cc.innerHTML) 
  {
     alert("New File");
  } //close If NewFile.rtf
  else {
     alert("Not new file");
  }
}//close Open()
```

Here I have string "NewFile.rtf" in a  element with id="FName" on the page. When the FName contains "Newfile.rtf" in it it stills goes to the else part of the function instead of going to if part. I tried different ways to write the compare statement in the if condition, no luck . Appreciate the help if anyone can help figure out this.

Thank you.

Comment: can we see your HTML portion of 'FName' please.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest explanation is that your cc.innerHTML call is not returning what you think it is returning.  Why don't you console.log or debug.

add something like

```
var innerhtml = cc.innerHTML;
console.log("innerHTML = " + innerhtml) // wont work in IE.
```

before the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **regular expressions** to find your filename, also check if the text you are searching is not into another DOM element, elimate left and right spaces, you should use Google Chrome for debuging the Javascript code:

```
var html = document.getElementById('FName').innerHTML; 
if( html.search("Newfile.rtf") != -1) { /*found*/ }
else { /*not found*/ }
```

Comment: what does the condition <> -1 means. This seems to be working . appreciate the help

Comment: @sony: the search() function returns the position of the searched string if found or -1 y not found. Operator might be !=, changed to reflect your observation.

Answer (score 0):

but what's the type of this element? if it's about an input text type .. you can't use innerHTML but you'll use value then.

Comment: <li id="FName">
                <%=FileName%>
            </li>

Comment: where FileName has "Newfile.rtf" string. I need this to work on IE

Comment: I wonder if we can define a li object as a var in javascript!

Comment: but if FileName="Newfile.rtf" string it will be : <%="Newfile.rtf"%>

Comment: I think the cc.innerHTML=="<%="Newfile.rtf"%>" not "Newfile.rtf"

Comment: In that case when I write alert(cc.innerHTML); it shows Newfile.rtf

Comment: if ('Newfile.rtf' == document.getElementById('FName').innerHTML) 
  {
     alert("New File");
  } //close If NewFile.rtf
  else {
     alert("Not new file");
  }

Comment: ah, I forget that <% is for some server language

Comment: Ok I took a work around stored the value in hidden field and accessed it by value in javscript .

Answer (score 0):

Use innerText to get that

```
function Open() {

    var cc = document.getElementById('FName');

    if ('Newfile.rtf' == cc.innerText)
    {
        alert("New File");
    } //close If NewFile.rtf
    else {
        //enter code here
        alert("Not new file");
    }
}
```